# What is the meaning of ^ON$ and ^OFF$ in url rewrite pattern and what matches this pattern

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I came across this rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
</conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

what is ON or OFF in pattern and what matches this pattern?

Comment: Why `pattern="^OFF$"` and not just `pattern="off"` ? `{https}` can return off or on. so why the regex boundries ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir very nice question. have you got the answer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The pattern OFF is make sure that the rule executes only when the request comes in over http or else you might end up in an infinite loop.

So add a condition stating that {HTTPS} is OFF.

the ^ = (start of string, or "negative" if at the start of a range)

the $ = (end of string)

though the extra start/stop characters seem redundant for this purpose

[Here is a blog that discusses inbound rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chiranth/archive/2014/06/12/url-rewrite-part-2-inbound-rules.aspx)

Comment: I have the OFF rule as perscribed in the guide but I still get the "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".  Looks like an infinite loop on http/https requests.  Do you have any idea why this is happening?  I even tried clearing the cookies as some sites suggest but no luck.

Comment: Dead link, results in a 404 now

Answer (score 0):

input={HTTPS} could provide two input values, either OFF (for NO-HTTPS request) or ON(for an HTTPS request). Hence, to which if the pattern value matches, the rule gets executed. And that is why pattern="OFF" makes sure that the request comes in over http. Accordingly the rule gets executed.